# MacVim output question

Tags: macvim

in some documents I open in MacVim I get `>>` next to my line numbers and I can't find out what the meaning is.

[image]

I have [janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/) installed and probably it is one of the plugins.

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is [syntastic](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2736) plugin :

> Syntastic is a syntax checking plugin that runs buffers through external syntax 
>   checkers as they are saved and opened. If syntax errors are detected, the user 
>   is notified and is happy because they didn't have to compile their code or 
>   execute their script to find them.

It comes with [a list of syntax checkers](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/tree/master/syntax_checkers) which "just" wraps tools [like `tidy` for `xhtml`](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/master/syntax_checkers/xhtml.vim)...